# HANA linestring to segments

Tags: geospatial, hana

How can I divide a linestring to line segments? using SAP HANA DB

for example:

```
'LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 5)'
```

will become:

```
'LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2) LINESTRING(2 2, 0 2) LINESTRING(0 2, 0 5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract individual points with the function ST_PointN().
To call it for point 1, 2, 3, ... N
I use a temp table called TMP that would store counter values:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP (NUM INT);
select TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER () from PUBLIC.M_TABLES ;
```

Then I apply ST_PointN for every point using the counter table.

```
select NUM, LS.ST_PointN(NUM).ST_WKT() as CUR_POINT
from(
    select NEW ST_LineString('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 5)') as LS, NUM
    from TMP    
)nested1    
where NUM<=LS.ST_NumPoints()
```

This returns

```
NUM| CUR_POINT  
1  |POINT (0 0)  
2  |POINT (2 2)  
3  |POINT (0 2)  
4  |POINT (0 5)
```

You can easily concatenate those into a ST_Multipoint geometry with an aggregation using ST_UnionAggr():

```
select ST_UnionAggr(CUR_POINT).ST_AsWKT()
from(
    select NUM, LS.ST_PointN(NUM) as CUR_POINT
    from(
        select NEW ST_LineString('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 5)') as LS,     NUM
        from TMP    
    )nested1    
    where NUM<=LS.ST_NumPoints()
)nested2
```

This returns

```
MULTIPOINT ((0 0),(2 2),(0 2),(0 5))
```

Note: we could do a loop instead of using a counter table.

Now for your exact question, we will build 3 ST_LineString() using a window function to combine the current point with the next one. There are multiple ways to write such a query, here's one:

```
select NEW ST_LineString('LineString ('||START_POINT.ST_X()||' '||START_POINT.ST_Y()||','||END_POINT.ST_X()||' '||END_POINT.ST_Y()||')').ST_AsWKT() as LS
from(
    select CUR_POINT as START_POINT,
           NEW ST_Point(FIRST_VALUE(CUR_POINT) OVER(order by NUM asc rows BETWEEN 1 following and 1 following) )as END_POINT
    from(
        select NUM, LS.ST_PointN(NUM) as CUR_POINT, LS.ST_NumPoints() as NB_POINTS
        from(
            select NEW ST_LineString('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 5)') as LS, NUM
            from TMP    
        )nested1    
        where NUM<=LS.ST_NumPoints()
    )nested2
)nested3 
where END_POINT is not null
```

Tada:

```
LS  
LINESTRING (0 0,2 2)  
LINESTRING (2 2,0 2)  
LINESTRING (0 2,0 5)
```